# Adding a 1-dimensional array to a POSIX Shared Memory Object in C

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory

I am working on a POSIX-based program that shares a memory object between two or more processes, aka a Server - Client program.

I have some issues with the Server side of the program. I know how to map memory using `mmap()` and how to work with the Object between two different processes/programs. However, I have an issue when adding an array of integers to a shared memory object.

I can use `sprintf()` to print the contents to the shared memory object, then increase (reallocate) space of the Shared Memory Object by simply saying `ptr += strlen(whatstringiamworkingwith);`

However, I do not know how to re-allocate memory to the object when it contains an array of integers in C. Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int *calcCollatz(int n) {
    int solution;

    int *collatzSeq = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int j = 0;

    while (n != 1) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            solution = n / 2;
            n = solution;
            collatzSeq[j] = n;
            j++;
            return collatzSeq;
        } else {
            solution = (3 * n) + 1;
            n = solution;
            collatzSeq[j] = n;
            j++;
            return collatzSeq;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int SIZE = 4096;          //size in bytes of Shared Memory Object
    const char *sharedObj = "Shm";  //name of the Shared memory Object
    int shm_fd;                     //Shared memory file descriptor
    void *ptrShm; //Pointer to shared memory object

    shm_fd = shm_open(sharedObj, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666); //Create Shared Memory Object
    ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);  //configure the size of the shared memory object
                              //Map the shared memory object in the space of the process
    ptrShm = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

    if (ptrShm == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("Map Failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    sprintf(ptrShm, argv[1]);
    ptrShm += strlen(argv[1]);

    sprintf(ptrShm, calcCollatz(atoi(argv[1])));
    ptrShm += sizeof(calcCollatz(atoi(argv[1])));


    printf("Writing the sequence to a shared memory object!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Am I even on the right track?

Comment: (1) You seem to understand C reasonably well. Is English your first language? You should know that doing `ptr  += ` *`something`* is not “reallocating space” or “re-allocating memory”; it’s just moving a pointer. (2) Since you’re programming in C (and not C++), I suggest that you cut back on your use of the word “object”. (3) The comments in your `main` are OK. The comments in your `calcCollatz` missing. Please add some. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. (4) It’s considered poor form for a function to modify its parameters. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Consider having `calcCollatz` declare a ``local_n`` variable, which is initialized to the value of `n`. (5) If your approach is set in stone now, so be it, but you might want to think about whether you really want to pass numeric data back and forth between processes by their ASCII string representations.

Comment: P.S. (6) A software suite that shares memory between two or more processes is not necessarily a Client-Server system, so your “aka” is inappropriate.  (7) Shared memory can be very useful for multi-process software suites, but it’s not necessarily the best choice for a client-server architecture.  (8) You should check the return code from ``shm_open`` for error.  (9) It’s considered poor form to return a negative value from `main`.  You should stick to values between 0 and 255 — ideally, between 0 and 125 — with 0 indicating success and anything else indicating failure.

Comment: You probably want to use [`mremap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) to expand the existing memory mapping by the number of bytes you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors and issues in your code.

1. `ptr += strlen(whatstringiamworkingwith);` is advancing a pointer, not
   reallocating memory.
2. Doing `sprintf(ptrShm, argv[1]);` is dangerous, if I execute your program
   like this: `./yourprogram %s` then you will have undefined behaviour as the `%s`
   specifier would be present but a pointer to `char*` to satisfy the specifier is
   missing. Never pass a variable filled by the user as the format for `printf` &
   Co. So do it like this:

   ```
   sprintf(ptrShm, "%s", argv[1]);
   ```

   Sames goes for this line: `sprintf(ptrShm, calcCollatz(atoi(argv[1])));`

   And you are not checking if there are enough command line arguments, you should
   add this at the beginning of your program:

   ```
   if(argc != 2)
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s data\n", argv[0]);
       return 1;
   }
   ```
3. Error messages should be printed to `stderr`, so instead of doing
   `printf("Map Failed\n");` you should do:

   ```
   fprintf(stderr, "Map failed\n");
   ```

   but that's not very informative, you should also print the value of `errno`
   like this:

   ```
   fprintf(stderr, "Map failed: %s\n", strerrno(errno));
   // or
   perror("Map failed");
   ```
4. You are not checking the return value `shm_open`.
5. The exit codes are signed 8 bit values, so doing `return -1` is equivalent to
   `return 255`.
6. As stated in the `shm_open` man page:

   > *man shm_open*
   >
   > a shared memory object should be identified by a name of the form `/somename`; that is, a null-terminated string of  up  to
   >          NAME_MAX (i.e., 255) characters **consisting of an initial slash**, followed by one or more characters, none of which are slashes.

   so the proper name should be

   ```
   const char *sharedObj = "/Shm";
   ```
7. `sizeof(calcCollatz(atoi(argv[1])));` is the same as `sizeof(int*)`, that
   mean the size of a pointer to `int`. And because `sizeof` is evaluated on
   compile-time, the function is actually never executed. You probably want to resize by the number
   of items. Not only that `ptr += size` is the incorrect call, you are getting the
   information completely wrong.

   Your `calcCollatz` is also wrong, you are allocating only space for one single
   `int`, why bother dynamically allocating space for a single `int`?
   Also you are doing `return collatzSeq` right away, again, why even bother
   dynamically allocating space for a single `int`? I thinks this is what you're
   looking for:

   ```
   int *calcCollatz(int n, size_t *len) {
       if(len == NULL)
           return NULL;

       int *collatzSeq = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
       *len = 0;

       while (n != 1) {
           // better than n % 2 == 0
           if (n & 1 == 0)
               n /= 2;
           else
               n = 3 * n + 1;

           tmp = realloc(collatzSeq, (*len + 1) * sizeof *collatzSeq);
           if(tmp == NULL)
           {
               free(collatzSeq);
               return NULL;
           }
           collatzSeq = tmp;

           collatzSeq[(*len)++] = n;
       }

       return collatzSeq;
   }
   ```
8. I don't really understand why you want to resize the mmap memory. Usually you
   know right away how much memory you need and if you need to store a dynamically
   generated array, then calculate the amount of memory you need, then create the
   shared memory, not the other way round:

   ```
   size_t base = 4096;
   size_t arrlen;

   int *arr = calcCollatz(atoi(argv[1]), &arrlen);
   if(arr == NULL)
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to do calculation\n");
       return 1;
   }

   size_t size = base + arrlen;

   shm_fd = shm_open(sharedObj, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
   if(shm_fd == -1)
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open shared memory: %s\n", strerror(errno));
       return 1;
   }
   ftruncate(shm_fd, size);

   ptrShm = mmap(0, size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

   if (ptrShm == MAP_FAILED) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Map Failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
       return 1;
   }

   printf("Writing the sequence to a shared memory object!\n");
   sprintf(ptrShm, "%s", argv[1]);

   // note that void* arithmetic is a GNU extension
   // otherwise you have to cast to (char*) before doing the
   // the arithmetic
   memcpy(ptrShm + base, arr, arrlen * sizeof *arr);

   free(arr);
   close(shm_fd);
   return 0;
   ```

   But if you insist in resizing the mmap memory later, then you can use
   [`mremap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html), but be aware that this is available in GNU/Linux only and you
   have to add `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before including `sys/mman.h`:

   ```
   size_t size = 4096;

   // create shared memory + mmap
   ...

   // exapanding mmap memory
   size_t arrlen;

   int *arr = calcCollatz(atoi(argv[1]), &arrlen);
   if(arr == NULL)
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to do calculation\n");
       close(shm_fd);
       return 1;
   }

   size_t newsize = size + arrlen * sizeof *arr;

   void *newptrShm = mremap(ptrShm, size, newsize, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);

   if(newptrShm == MAP_FAILED)
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "Failed to expand memory: %s\n", strerror(errno));
       free(arr);
       close(shm_fd);
       return 1;
   }

   ptrShm = newptrShm;

   // resize shared file size
   ftruncate(shm_fd, newsize);

   memcpy(ptrShm + base, arr, arrlen * sizeof *arr);

   free(arr);

   ...
   ```

   See also: [Fast resize of a mmap file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703820/fast-resize-of-a-mmap-file) and
   [How to portably extend a file accessed using `mmap()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684771/how-to-portably-extend-a-file-accessed-using-mmap)